# Issue to compile protobuf-c on MIPS target system

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling

This is cross compile issue.

I crated [xxxx.proto](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c) and generated C code by using protobuf-c project. It was compiled successfully on x86 linux.

But when I cross compiled it for MIPS, then it made compile error. I compiled protobuf, protobuf-c by using buildroot. And toolchain is sorcery tools.

The source code is like below.

```
#include <string.h>
#include "egmessage.pb-c.h"  //header file that protobuf-c generated. I never touched it. 

int main (void)
{
    printf("Hello, world.");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this code by using command below.

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc egmessage.pb-c.c test.c -o extest -I/home/vagrant/tools/buildroot-2014.11/output/staging/usr/include -lprotobuf-c
```

Then I got the compile error like below.

```
In file included from test.c:6:0:
egmessage.pb-c.h:20:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' b
efore 'typedef'
 typedef struct _ControlMessage ControlMessage;
 ^
egmessage.pb-c.h:35:23: error: unknown type name 'ControlMessage'
                      (ControlMessage         *message);
                       ^
egmessage.pb-c.h:37:22: error: unknown type name 'ControlMessage'
                      (const ControlMessage   *message);
                      ^
egmessage.pb-c.h:39:22: error: unknown type name 'ControlMessage'
                      (const ControlMessage   *message,
                      ^
egmessage.pb-c.h:42:22: error: unknown type name 'ControlMessage'
                      (const ControlMessage   *message,
                      ^
egmessage.pb-c.h:44:1: error: unknown type name 'ControlMessage'
 ControlMessage *
 ^
egmessage.pb-c.h:50:23: error: unknown type name 'ControlMessage'
                      (ControlMessage *message,
                       ^
egmessage.pb-c.h:54:18: error: unknown type name 'ControlMessage'
                  (const ControlMessage *message,
                  ^
test.c:8:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'

 int main (void)
 ^
```

Error message said it want to use several symbol. Have you the experience like that?

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd recommend better to use nano-pb for c-bindings.

Comment: Open up the file and check what comes immediately before the line 20 'typedef'. The first error (and the only relevant one) is "Something is missing before this typedef".

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason. I used protobuf I compiled manually. That version is different from buildroot's protobuf version. I applied buildroot's protobuf and compiled proto file again. Then it worked.